Did Krsna tell Bhishma not to interfere in the dice game?
In the movie "Mahabharata" directed by Peter Brooks, Krsna asks Bhishma not to interfere in the dice game.  Is this narrative true? It seems to conflict with the answer posted here, and the following:

Then Yudhishthira put the kingdom at stake and lost it. People were
looking on in dismay. Bhishma stood up and said, “Stop the game.”
Duryodhana shouted him down, “It is not for you to stop the game. We
are playing this game as per the dharma of the Kshatriyas. If
Yudhishthira is afraid of playing the game, he may leave. No one else
can stop the game.


This narrative is false. Shri Krishna did not want the Pandavas to lose the game. Otherwise he would not have protected Draupadi during Cheer Haran.

@RV10 which narrative?  Does Bhishma interfere at all?

If you read the entire Mahabharat you will realise that Bhishma and Drona were topmost devotees, and had immense self control and willpower. They could have gotten down from their seats and stopped everything. In the modern sense we can't understand, but back in the day these so called yogis repeatedly showed their allegiance to Kauravas. Bhishma even mentioned that money from Kauravas was a reason for his support from them.


What we often fail to realize is that Lord Krishna was neither the protector of the Pandavas nor the destroyer of the Kauravas. He was the embodiment of dharma (righteousness), acting as its supreme establisher, and remained neither a friend nor an enemy to anyone.

For reference - this is what Lord Krishna says to Yudhishthira in the Vana Parva of the Mahabharata, explaining how he would have prevented the dice game from ever taking place:

Vasudeva said, "O lord of earth, if I had been present at Dwaraka, then, O king, this evil would not have befallen thee! And, O irrepressible one, coming unto the gambling-match, even if uninvited by the son of Ambika (Dhritarashtra), or Duryodhana, or by the other Kauravas, I would have prevented the game from taking place.


Interestingly Bhagwan Krishna is with Arjun and other Pandavas in almost every difficult situations, but during the game of dice he was absent due to certain unforeseen circumstances - (he has been attacked by Salva, enraged by his brother Sisupala’s death.)

As Narayana, or the supreme one, Lord Krishna may only serve as a witness to the unfolding of events, as individuals exercise their free will, while the universal order continuously arranges and rearranges itself in response.

ईश्वर: सर्वभूतानां हृद्देशेऽर्जुन तिष्ठति |
भ्रामयन्सर्वभूतानि यन्त्रारूढानि मायया ||

The Supreme Lord dwells in the hearts of all living beings, O Arjun. According to their karmas, He directs the wanderings of the souls, who are seated on a machine made of material energy.
Hare Krishna!!
